# MySQL 8 TLS/SSL error. Wrong number version

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, java-ee-6, mysql-8.0

I searched a lot regarding this matter but unfortunately, I could not find anything helpful.
I have an application in JAVA EE deployed in Payara Glassfish server. This application connects with SSL in on-premise database. MySQL version 8. Everything was working properly until I got the below message.

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: connecting to destination failed with TLS error: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:446)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:417)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:129)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:114)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource.getXAConnection(MysqlXADataSource.java:52)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     at com.sun.gjc.spi.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:118)
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52     ... 66 more
> 2024-03-06T08:32:52 ]]

This error appears also when I try to connect from my latest Dbeaver client. DBeaver 24.0.0
I understand that this is related to TLS version and maybe SSL ciphers, but this is not proved while I use TLSv1.3

I tried to connect also from my MySQL CLI client with version `mysql  Ver 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`. In this case, the behavior is strange because sometimes I can connect and sometimes not. Also, I created a Java maven app with Java 11 so I could focus on the connection. I used mysql connector 8.0.33 and 8.3.0. Again sometimes I can connect and sometimes I cannot. When the connection is successful it takes a long to respond. Its important to mention that exists a MySQL router in front of the cluster.

Thank you!

As I mentioned in my message above I tried to minimize the problem and focus on the issue regarding the connection.
I tried connecting from

- Java 11 with JDBC
- MySQL client CLI
- DBeaver client

Comment: *"I understand that this is related with TLS version and maybe ssl ciphers"* - The error messages it is not related to ciphers. And in many (most?) cases it is not related to TLS version either, although "wrong version number" very much suggest that it should. This error message happens also when a TLS response is expected but instead a non-TLS response is received, but the bytes 2 and 3 of this response are blindly interpreted as TLS version number.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is there a way to prove that a non-TLS response is received? Why sometimes I can connect and some not. Does this mean that sometimes there is a TLS response? When I connect I use --ssl-mode=VERIFY_CA. Should I change that to PREFERRED in this case? Because I do not have access to the database, how can this be approached from client side?

Comment: With `--ssl-mode=PREFERRED` you might succeed if the other side does not offer SSL.Why it sometimes works and sometimes not is unclear though.

Comment: I would like to add a detail that I did not share. There is a MySQL router in front of the cluster. I added this detail in the description of the issue.

Comment: Your title does not accurately quote the error message. Don’t do that. Don’t paraphrase or misquote error messages. Precision please.

Comment: *" There is a MySQL router in front of the cluster. "* - so you are not connecting to a single myself database instance but to a cluster. Maybe the instances are configured differently regarding tls and that's why it sometimes works and sometimes not.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry for that, I am new to this even that my account openned some time ago. Can you give me an example and I will edit the title. Should it be like this "connecting to destination failed with TLS error: error:0A00010B:SSL routines::wrong version number". The goal of this question is not only for me to solve my issue but for sure for other people that might have the same issue to find a solution.